# Strip letters in php

Tags: php, strip

We have variable with text:

```
$text = 'I use something similar to pull the most recent post from my blog and display a snapshot of it on my home page.';
```

**How to strip first 40 symbols of this text?** (including spaces).

Should work like this:

```
echo strip_text($text, 40);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use PHP's [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$stripped = substr($text, 0, 40);
```

Comment: He wants to strip the first 40 characters, not output them.

Comment: The reason you've been downvoted is because your answer is wrong: your answer outputs the first 40 characters of `$text` rather than stripping the first 40 characters.

Comment: @Mark Trapp: your solution also outputs the text.

Answer (score 2):

With [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
echo substr($text, 40);
```

Comment: He wants to strip the first 40 characters, not output them.

Comment: The reason you've been downvoted is because your answer is wrong: your answer outputs the first 40 characters of $text rather than stripping the first 40 characters.

Comment: your solution is wrong, it gives 40 letters from the end of the string.

Comment: seems someone doesn't think before upvoting an answer

Comment: No, my solution strips the first 40 characters, and returns the rest of the string, as you had asked for in your question. `substr($text, -40)` would return the last 40 characters of the string, and `substr($text, 0, 40)` would return the first 40 characters.